# Visual Studio ClassWizard error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, mfc, msvc12, classwizard

I am getting ClassWizard startup error for my class in MSVC 2013.

```
    ---------------------------
    Microsoft Visual Studio
    ---------------------------
    Failed to retrieve controls of dialog 'XYZ'.
    ---------------------------
    OK   
    ---------------------------
```

Then it opens but dialog controls and message handlers are not recognized.

The dialog uses all standard MFC controls.

All resource id values in resource.h are unique.

I tried to put marks like `//{{AFX_DATA`, `{{AFX_MSG`, etc. where appropriate. No effect.

I tried to generate a new class for the same dialog id. ClassWizard gives the same message while starting on the new class.

It seems like there is something it doesn't like in my project or resource files.

Any ideas?
Is there a way to diagnose this thing?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you get the same message on a different project?  Have you tried repairing Visual Studio?

Comment: It works on other projects.

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but, in the past, I've enabled [project system logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/21/enable-c-project-system-logging.aspx) to diagnose other problems.

Comment: Thanks, cool idea, I've actually tried this too. No messages from ClassWizard though.

Comment: There is no appropriate place to put `//{{AFX_DATA` and similar comments in Visual Studio 2010 and later. Those comments were used up to and including Visual Studio 6.

Comment: I would delete all pch, sdf, suo, ncb files and tried reloading the project again

Comment: Deleting the files did not help. I've got a few "Exception from HRESULT: 0x8CE0000B" during the rebuild.

Comment: How did you fix this error @vt?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you are having the resources in a separate project while the associated classes (source code) are in different project.

Comment: This might've been the case. Thanks

Comment: For me it is the case, and I am getting this error on all classes. I wonder if it's possible to make the Class Wizard recognize it and work around that fact.